# rails 5 collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, collection-select

I am trying to make a `collection_select` that I get a drop down with the values of a field from another model. I got the following 2 models:

`Documents`:

```
class CreateDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :documents do |t|
      t.string :etiquette_number
      t.string :etiquette_type
      t.boolean :important
      t.string :work_text
      t.integer :user_id


      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

`Entries`:

```
class CreateEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :entries do |t|
      t.integer :document_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :work
      t.date :date
      t.integer :time

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I want to get a dropdown select on `document_id` (in `Entries` model), where I can select the values of the id of a document.

I got this so far but I am not sure if it is the right way

`models/document.rb`

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :Entries
end
```

`models/entry.rb`

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Documents
end
```

I really hope that someone can help me and as you see in the title I am using Rails 5.

Comment: Try `has_many :entries` and `belongs_to :documents`

Comment: but I named my models Entry and Document. is it still :entries and  :documents?

Comment: Yep :) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: okey thanks and I think it is possible with collection_select http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select but don't know how

Comment: I want to show that drop down in the front end. sorry I forgot to write this

Comment: so you want list of `entries` right?

Comment: no in the entries table in the document_id field I want that I can select the id of a document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :entries
end


class Entry < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :document
end
```

In your view file like: new.html.erb

```
 <%= f.select :document_id, Document.all.collect { |p| p.id }, include_blank: true %>
```

Comment: I get this error: undefined method `name' for #<Document:0x007ffc9d63a370>

Comment: <%= f.select :document_id, Document.all.collect { |p|  p.id }, include_blank: true %>

Answer (score 1):

You should use associations as below code

when you are using `has_many` then model name should be `plural`

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entries
end
```

And when you are using `belongs_to` then model name should be `singular`

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :document
end
```

you can write select tag inside your `entry` from like below

```
 @documents = Document.all

 <%= f.select :document_id, @documents.collect { |d| [ d.name, d.id ] }, include_blank: true %>
```

@documents is the insurance variable which has all the documents.

Thanks

Comment: ah okey thanks for that. and you now how I can show that in the front-end (like a html select) with the values of the id of the Documents in the document_id field?

Comment: you can show `entries` list on view not the document. because you have relation like `Document has_many :entries`.

Comment: okey no problem. think my answer was a little unclear.. sorry for that

Comment: i get this error: undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass

Comment: you have to add @documents variable inside your controller action. i.e documents = Document.all

Answer (score 0):

You need to scope the documents to the ones that belong to that entry

```
<%= f.select :document_id, entry.documents, include_blank: true %>
```